# How to integrate HIVE access into PySpark derived from pip and conda (not from a Spark distribution or package)

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hive-metastore

I build and programmatically use my `PySpark` environment from the ground-up via `conda` and `pip` pyspark (like I demonstrate [Here](https://jupyter.ai/pyspark-session/)); rather than use `PySpark` from the downloadable Spark distribution. As you can see in the first code-snippet of the URL above, I accomplish this through (among other things) k/v conf-pairs in my SparkSession startup script. (By the way, this approach enables me to do work in various REPLs, IDEs and JUPYTER).

However, with respect to configuring Spark support for accessing HIVE databases and metadata-stores, the manual says this:

> Configuration of `Hive` is done by placing your `hive-site.xml`, `core-site.xml` (for security configuration), and `hdfs-site.xml` (for HDFS configuration) file in `conf/`.

By `conf/` above they mean the `conf/` directory in the Spark distribution package. But `pyspark` via `pip` and `conda` doesn't have that directory, of course, so how might HIVE database and metastore support be plugged into Spark in that case?

I suspect this might be accommodated by specially-prefixed SparkConf K/V pairs of the form: `spark.hadoop.*` (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration)); and if yes, I'd still need to determine which HADOOP / HIVE / CORE directives are needed. I guess I'll trial & error that. :)

**Note**: `.enableHiveSupport()` has already been included.

I'll tinker with `spark.hadoop.*` K/V pairs, but if anyone knows how this is done offhand, please do let me know.

Thank you. :)

**EDIT**: After the solution was provided, I updated the content in the [first URL above](https://jupyter.ai/pyspark-session/). It now integrates the `SPARK_CONF_DIR` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable approach discussed below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I'd recommend [the official configuration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) (emphasis mine):

> If you plan to read and write from HDFS using Spark, there are two Hadoop configuration files that should be included on Spark’s classpath:
>
> - hdfs-site.xml, which provides default behaviors for the HDFS client.
> - core-site.xml, which sets the default filesystem name.
>
> (...)
>
> **To make these files visible to Spark, set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`** to a location containing the configuration files.

[Additionally](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#overriding-configuration-directory):

> **To specify a different configuration directory other than the default “`SPARK_HOME/conf`”, you can set `SPARK_CONF_DIR`**. Spark will use the configuration files (spark-defaults.conf, spark-env.sh, log4j.properties, etc) from this directory.

So it is possible to use arbitrary directory accessible to your Spark installation to place desired configuration files, and `SPARK_CONF_DIR` and / or `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` can be easily set directly in your script, using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ).

Finally there is even no need for separate Hadoop configuration files, most of the time, as Hadoop specific properties can be set directly in Spark documentation, using `spark.hadoop.*` prefix.

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot about `SPARK_CONF_DIR`; and I agree with you in preferring to use `spark.hadoop.*` prefixed-keys over separate Hadoop XML configuration files. I'm working on the latter now. Thank you for confirming that in this, the marked, answer.